# Hive null values remove

Tags: sql, hive, null, floating-point, hiveql

I am facing a problem in removing null values from latitude and longitude columns in hive. 
I used replace2 function and all others given on stackoverflow, but I am not getting all the null values removed. 
Datatype is floating point

Initial data- 80 million records
After my code - 60 million
But actual data without null values should be 45 million

Comment: please provide some example of initial data and the desired result. It is not clear whar remove nulls means

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select * from data_table
 where (latitude is not null) and (longitude is not null)
```